# Configure Error Readline Headers not Available R

Tags: r, readline

First off I realize that this question has been answered. I found that the top hit provided little explanation of the solution. Also my situation is different in the sense that I have no package manager and no root privileges. I hope this questions enables other users like me to be able to install R.

So here is my problem. I am installing R version 3.3.2 and it is giving me an error during configuration:

```
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

I read online about readlines and how it should be downloaded readline library version 7.0 from the GNU website and installed it in my own directory using

```
./configure --prefix=/home/readlines; make; make install
```

Now I just can't get R to recongize where the libraries are. I tried the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/readlines:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
./configure --prefix=/home/R-3.3.2/ CPPFLAGS="-I/home/readlines/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/home/readlines/lib"
```

I also tried setting CFLAGS to no avail. Can anyone help me figure out how to tell R where my readlines headers are? I'm on CentOS 7

Comment: What platform / OS are you on?

Comment: Updated question to reflect OS version: CentOS 7

Comment: You are doing this somewhat wrong.  There will be a package called `libreadline-dev` or `libreadline-devel`; install that.  R should then find the headers.  You may have to move on to the next library.  See the `R Administration and Installation` guide, and maybe check with the r-sig-fedora list for RH and its derivatives.

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git?h=devel I have installed this and linked it the same way but I still get the same message

Comment: Not. At. All.  I said _package_.  Install a _prebuilt_ rpm which will place files _in the right spots_.

Comment: Have you installed from source before on any other machine? Do you know what `configure; make; make install` refers to?  Installation from source requires a certain mindset; this is not hard --- but something moderately rich like R is not the best place to start.  Maybe [try this](https://www.google.com/search?q=install+R+rpm+on+CentOS&oq=install+R+rpm+on+CentOS).

Comment: As stated in my question I am not able to install packages as I do not have a package manager that I can use. I am only able to install from source, and yes I do know what configure, make, make install refer to.

Comment: No package manager means no root access. Which means no system libraries at all.   That is doable, but _a lot of work_.  There may be some tutorials for you.

Comment: You are currently fighting an issue unrelated to R. I would try to build a small readline-using (example or test) executable against your non-standard local readline installation.  Once that works, get R to recognise it.  You will have to debug why configure does not find this, and probably read the source snippets of your configure script.

Comment: For all the best support R can give, try the aforementioned [R Installation and Administration manul](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html), particularly Appendix B and other Unix material.

Comment: Yes I realize this, I also mention that I do not have root access in my question. I was hoping somebody here would have experience in linking libraries, or be able to point out what it is that I am missing here. I find it extremely difficult to find any tutorials that do not involve `yum`. I'll keep looking

Comment: Go beyond any tutorials for a distro, ie discard the ones for both `yum` and `apt`.  You need to learn how to tame `configure`.  Good luck.

Comment: Did you figure it out by any chance? I'm having exactly the same problem